# ADMIN option not granted for role 'my_role_1'

Tags: sql, oracle, database-administration, user-roles, sql-grant

I am trying to grant a role to user.

```
grant my_role_1 to ktest1 with admin option;
```

But i am getting the below error

```
Error report - ORA-01932: ADMIN option not granted for role 'my_role_1'
01932. 00000 -  "ADMIN option not granted for role '%s'
*Cause:    The operation requires the admin option on the role.
*Action:   Obtain the grant option and re-try.
```

Answer (score 1):

As [`GRANT` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9013.htm#i2155015) says:

> To grant a role, you must either have been granted the role with the `ADMIN OPTION` or have been granted the `GRANT ANY ROLE` system privilege, or you must have created the role.